# .htaccess not working for site which is not at root level

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hosted my site at not root level in `www.example.com/~abc/`. here is kept my `.htaccess` file and all rewrite rules are defined. But they doesn't seems to work properly. Like `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php` is not working. when i am opening www.example.com/~abc/random it is giving 404 with additional 404 that `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` i kept my 404 at `www.example.com/~abc/errors/404.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to anubhava, here is my answer that worked
`ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/~abc/errors/404.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `relative path` for 404:

```
ErrorDocument 404 errors/404.php
```

Comment: what is differce in /errors/404.php and errors/404.php ? btw i triedn your method and it just showing errors/404.php on screen

Comment: Is this .htaccess is even enabled? Can you verify that?